# Scroll to a custom component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to scroll to the position of a custom component but the ref to it isn't returning a valid html node. The method "goToContactUs" should perform the action. Which would be the best way to do this?

```
class Help extends Component {
    constructor () {
        super();

        this.goToContactUs = this.goToContactUs.bind(this);
    }

    goToContactUs () {
        this.contactUs.scrollIntoView();
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <ToggleContainer
                    title={this.props.strings['Contact Us']} 
                    show={this.props.help.showContactUs}
                    toggle={this.contactUsHandler}
                    ref={(div) => { this.contactUs = div }}
                >
                    <ContactUs sendEmail={this.props.sendEmail} emailSuccess={this.props.help.emailSuccess} />
                </ToggleContainer>                  
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change the `scrollTop` of the `ToggleContainer` to be the top of the `ContactUs`.

Since `ContactUs` will be an instance of that element you can use `findDOMNode` to get its node representation.

```
import { findDOMNode } from 'react-dom';

class Help extends Component {
  // ... omitted
  scrollToContact() {
    const yPos = findDOMNode(this.contact).offsetTop;
    this.container.scrollTop = yPos;
  }

  contact = null;
  container = null;

  render() {
    return (<div>
      <ToggleContainer
        title={this.props.strings['Contact Us']} 
        show={this.props.help.showContactUs}
        toggle={this.contactUsHandler}
        ref={container => this.container = container}
      >
        <ContactUs
          ref={contact => this.contact = contact}
          sendEmail={this.props.sendEmail}
          emailSuccess={this.props.help.emailSuccess}
        />
     </ToggleContainer>                  
   </div>);
  }
}
```